# Scala - Computing strongly connected components - stack overflow error

Tags: algorithm, scala

I am currently following Tim Roughgarden's Algorithms specialisation on Coursera and the module 2, week 1 assignment involves calculating the size of strongly connected components in a graph. I can compute them for smaller size graphs but the problem question has ~ 5 million edges. I got a solution working fairly quickly but have spent hours trying to get it to run on the full set, short of me buying some time on an AWS super computer, could anyone help me to find a way around this stack overflow error?

I have left off the pre-processing step where I get the array into an adjacency list and pass it into the master_dfs in the correct order.

```
import scala.io.Source

object Main extends App {

  def dfs(adjList: Map[Int, List[Int]], currentNode: Int,
          foundNodes: Set[Int], finishingTime: List[Int]): (Set[Int], 
                                                           List[Int]) = {

    val foundsWithCurrent: Set[Int] = foundNodes + currentNode

    val edges: List[Int] = adjList(currentNode)

    val crossOver: List[Int] = edges.filterNot(node => 
                                       foundNodes.contains(node))

    if (crossOver.nonEmpty) {
       val (nextStepFinds, nextStepFinishers) = 
          dfs(adjList, crossOver.head, foundsWithCurrent, finishingTime)

       dfs(adjList, currentNode,
          nextStepFinds, nextStepFinishers)
    }

    else (foundsWithCurrent, currentNode :: finishingTime)

    }


  def master_dfs(orderOfExecution: List[Int], adjList: Map[Int, 
    List[Int]], foundNodes: Set[Int], finishedList: List[Int], sccs: 
    List[List[Int]]): (Set[Int], List[Int], List[List[Int]]) = {

    val (foundThisPass, finishers) = dfs(adjList = adjList,
      currentNode = orderOfExecution.head, foundNodes = foundNodes, 
      finishingTime = finishedList)

    val scc: List[Int] = finishers.filterNot(node => 
    finishedList.contains(node))

    val leftToExecute = orderOfExecution.filterNot(node => 
    foundThisPass.contains(node))

    if (leftToExecute.isEmpty) {
        (foundThisPass, finishers, scc :: sccs)
      }

    else {
       master_dfs(orderOfExecution = leftToExecute, adjList = adjList,
       foundNodes = foundThisPass, finishedList = finishers, sccs = 
                                   scc :: sccs)
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since stack space is limited in most languages, you always need to think about how much of it you're going to use when you implement an algorithm recursively.

Implementing DFS recursively is OK on trees or DAGs when you know that search depth, i.e the maximum path length to any node, is limited.

On general directed or undirected graphs, however, the longest path in the graph may include a large proportion of the vertexes in the graph, and the call depth of a recursive DFS implementation can be as long as that path.  That can cause a stack overflow for large inputs.

When you don't know for certain that all the input graphs will be shallow enough to be safe, you should implement the DFS iteratively using a stack object instead of recursively using the call stack.

Since a stack object doesn't have the same limitations that the call stack does, the iterative implementation can handle much larger inputs.